# Reading excel files from "input" blob storage container and exporting to csv in "output" container with python

Tags: python, python-3.x, azure-blob-storage, export-to-csv, xlsx

I'm trying to develop a script in python to read a file in *.xlsx* from a blob storage container called "source", convert it in *.csv* and store it in a new container (I'm testing the script locally, if working I should include it in an ADF pipeline). So far, I managed to access to the blob storage, but I'm having problems in reading the file content.

```
from azure.storage.blob import BlobServiceClient, ContainerClient, BlobClient
import pandas as pd

conn_str = "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=XXXXXX;AccountKey=XXXXXX;EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net"
container = "source"
blob_name = "prova.xlsx"

container_client = ContainerClient.from_connection_string(
    conn_str=conn_str, 
    container_name=container
    )
# Download blob as StorageStreamDownloader object (stored in memory)
downloaded_blob = container_client.download_blob(blob_name)

df = pd.read_excel(downloaded_blob)

print(df)
```

I get following error:

> ValueError: Invalid file path or buffer object type: <class 'azure.storage.blob._download.StorageStreamDownloader'>

I tried with a *.csv* file as input and writing the parsing code as follows:

```
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(downloaded_blob.content_as_text()) )
```

and it works.

Any suggestion on how to modify the code so that the excel file becomes readable?

Comment: Please try to use `df = pd.read_excel(downloaded_blob.content_as_bytes())`

Comment: Hi @JimXu I've just opened the ticket to write that I found the solution on StorageStreamDownloader class page (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-storage-blob/azure.storage.blob.storagestreamdownloader?view=azure-python#content-as-bytes-max-concurrency-1-) and I saw your answer: I can confirm that with .content_as_bytes() it works. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 2):

I summary the solution as below.

When we use the method `pd.read_excel()` in sdk `pandas`, we need to provide bytes as input. But when we use `download_blob` to download the excel file from azure blob, we just get `azure.storage.blob.StorageStreamDownloader`. So we need to use the method `readall()` or `content_as_bytes()` to convert it to bytes. For more details, please refer to the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-storage-blob/azure.storage.blob.containerclient?view=azure-python#download-blob-blob--offset-none--length-none----kwargs-) and the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-storage-blob/azure.storage.blob.storagestreamdownloader?view=azure-python#content-as-bytes-max-concurrency-1-)

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
df = pd.read_excel(downloaded_blob)
```

to

```
df = pd.read_excel(downloaded_blob.content_as_bytes())
```